# Nginx, Opencart проблема с кириллицей в route=product/search

Tags: nginx, opencart

Моя голова уже вся сломалась на раздумьях о том, почему не проходит запрос в product/search на кириллице.

Opencart 2 на nginx + php-fpm.

Вбиваю русское слово в строку поиска (или прямо в адресную строку в /index.php?route=product/search&search=слово). Русское слово кодируется методом URIencode, например "погрузчик" -> "%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA"

Идет запрос `/index.php?route=product/search&search=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA`

В этой строке почему то последовательности "%8?" подменяются на "_" (посмотрела в логах), соответственно, запрос превращается в `/search/?search=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1_%D1_%D0%B7%D1_%D0%B8%D0%BA`

При раскодировании получается пустая строка, которая отправляется в базу данных, поиск ничего не находит.

Запросы на английском языке - работают. Запросы на русском языке - работают, если закодированное слово не содержит последовательностей "%8?", например, запрос "мини" пройдет.

Статические страницы с кириллицей (которые без route) - работают.
На локали на http - все работает.

Подозрения на какие то особенности конфига.
Конфиг домена:

```html
server {
  charset UTF-8;
    listen      IP:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domen.ru www.domen.ru;
    root        $root-path;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
 

    ssl_certificate      $ssl_certificate-path;
    ssl_certificate_key  $ssl_certificate_key-path;
 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }
    }
  
  location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }
 

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
 

    location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
 

    location /vstats/ {
        alias   $home-path/web/domen.ru/stats/;
        include $home-path/conf/web/domen.ru.auth*;
    }
 

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }
 

    if ($http_host = www.domen.ru){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://domen.ru$1 permanent;
    }
 

    #Редирект на https
    if ($scheme != "https"){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
 

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;
    include     $home-path/conf/web/snginx.domen.ru.conf*;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдена причина бага в seo_url.php файле.
При переходе на страницу, схожую с такой:
example.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=что_то_на_кириллице
Происходит обрезание и/или искажение кириллических символов (например в такой вид: example.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=).

Это из-за работы функции parse_url() - она не поддерживает кириллические значения get-параметров url.

parse_url используется в example.com/catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php (метод rewrite($link))

Для исправления нужно перед вызовом функции parse_url сделать url_encode для проблемных значений или же заменить parse_url на аналогичную совместимую с utf-8 функцию

Answer (score 1):

Пишу итоговое решение.

Не удалось найти, где происходит подмена символов, но проблема явно в SEO_URL, так как если его отключить, все работает. Решили отключить ЧПУ-ссылки именно на странице поиска. Страницы, связанные с поиском, все равно перекрыты в robots.txt и не влияют на сео сайта:

Disallow: /*route=product/search
Disallow: /search/

В файле\catalog\controller\startup\seo_pro.php в функции validate():

if (rawurldecode($url) != rawurldecode($seo) && isset($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])) {
header($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
$this->response->redirect($seo, 301);
}
замена на:

if (strripos($url, '/search')){ //со страниц поиска не редиректить на чпу, то есть ничего не делать
}

elseif ( rawurldecode($url) != rawurldecode($seo) && isset($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])) {
header($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
$this->response->redirect($seo, 301);
}

Примечание, сюда $url и $seo доходят еще нормальные и даже правильно расшифрованы, но во время редиректа с ними что-то происходит. Возможно, в WINDOWS-1251 перекодирует (хотя все страницы сайта, все таблицы базы данных, сама база, в настройке nginx установлено utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

На debian 11, nginx, php7.4-fpm была та же проблема.

Системная локаль по умолчанию стояла `en_US` и в lacales.gen `en_US ISO-8859-1`

```
apt remove locales-all
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Выбирать только UTF локали, по умолчанию поставил en_US.UTF8

```
reboot
```